Identify this 6 pin IC
What IC is this? It is used in a headlight.




Where is this from? Post the whole board.

The marking is hard to read, especially the second character.

why do you need to identify the component?

Because the light is dead , everything else checked out , only this piece could be the culprit

what about the butchered looking components in the second picture? ... or the resistor to the left of the IC

That whole board could be toast now anyway, because you decided placed it on a goddang synthetic carpet! Ever heard of ESD? I can't think of any worse place for a PCBA to be than on top of a synthetic carpet with long threads like this. Might as well hit the board with a sledgehammer.

@jsotola ...or the evil-looking solder mask crack on the 3rd pic.

It's very likely a PIC10(L)F320/322 MCU made by Microchip. I'm not sure what the second character of the marking is, but it looks like a C or G which would both be valid markings.
The part seems to be connected to the transistors and the switch, so I think a MCU makes sense function wise. It's probably used to control the different light modes that can be set by the switch.



(Picture of the PIC10F320T-I/OT from LCSC)

Update:
I traced the connections to the testpoints labeled DT, CK and VPP and it matches the PIC's pinout. I'm now very sure it's the PIC microcontroller.



This means simply replacing the part is not very useful because you also need a copy of the software that runs on it.

Nice. +1 Microchip parts would not be unexpected in a product like a $$$ Petzel headlamp.
